# Extract a substring in a column which is delimited by two specific characters in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains a column 'Wage' and I want to extract the numbers since this column contains a format like this: '€123K'
so I only want to preserve the string of numbers between the two characters **€** and **K** so that I get a new column 'Wage2' with only numbers.

Comment: New or not, read documentation! You are looking for the method `.str.extract()`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and if all values are integers is possible convert by `astype`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Wage':['€123K', '€723K']})

df['Wage2'] = df['Wage'].str.extract('€(.*?)K', expand=False).astype(int)
print (df)
    Wage  Wage2
0  €123K    123
1  €723K    723
```

Comment: @DyZ - Thank you :)